# Get original partitioning clause with DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL

Tags: oracle

I created a table in Oracle with:

```
CREATE TABLE schema.table_name
(
   col_1                 NUMBER(15),
   col_2                 NUMBER(10),
   col_3                 NUMBER(10),
   col_4                 NUMBER,

)
PARTITION BY HASH (col_1) PARTITIONS 32;
```

However, when I fetch with:

```
select  DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE', table_name, owner) ddl
                , table_name 
             from all_tables 
            where owner = 'schema'
              and table_name = 'table_name';
```

I get:

```
CREATE TABLE schema.table_name
(
   col_1                 NUMBER(15),
   col_2                 NUMBER(10),
   col_3                 NUMBER(10),
   col_4                 NUMBER,

)
NOLOGGING
PARTITION BY HASH (col_1)
 (PARTITION "SYS_P1" , 
  PARTITION "SYS_P2" , 
  PARTITION "SYS_P3" , 
  PARTITION "SYS_P4" , 
  PARTITION "SYS_P5" ,
  ....
  PARTITION "SYS_P32");
```

I've tried all of these parameters:

```
DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(
    DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM,'STORAGE',false);      
DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(
    DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM,'TABLESPACE',false);   
DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(
    DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM,'SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES',false);       
DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(
    DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM,'SQLTERMINATOR',true);     
DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(
    DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM,'PRETTY',true)
```

Is there a way to get the DDL back into the original format?

Comment: Have you tried setting PARTITIONING to false as you did with the others?

Comment: Yes, that will exclude the whole partitioning clause.  I noticed that I also lost, NOLOGGING (will need that, but I'm sure it's related to SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES or such).

Comment: It might work with [auditing](https://community.oracle.com/message/14786720#14786720), but it seems to me that you are searching for something lighter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot regain the initial statement you used to create the table/index/foreign key/whatever.

The DDL statement oracle provides here is a DDL statement to produce the exact same result as it is currently existing. In your case this yields a very short result, as it also mentions storage, parallel, tablespace, buffer_pool, etc etc when I try this with my tables.

Therefore, `...PARTITION BY HASH (col_1) (PARTITION "SYS_P1" , .... PARTITION "SYS_P32");...` may produce another result than `...PARTITION BY HASH (col_1) PARTITIONS 32;...`. An example here would be to [use another tablespace](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/part_admin001.htm#CHDDDCDB) or compress option.

What if some default options of your database change and you still want to regain the exact table you had before? When you created teh table, it wasn't compressed. Now it would be if it's the current default value with that same statement you used a while ago.

**TL;DR**

**Answer:** No

**Why:** You cannot reproduce the exact same object with the few options given on creation time, all other not given options are being taken from the default settings of the DB. These may change in time.

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate those unnecessary partition details with regexp_replace function. I use the following code:

```
mystr := regexp_replace ( regexp_replace ( mystr, ' \(*PARTITION [^(BY)](.|[:cntrl:])+', null, 1, 0, 'm'), '^[[:cntrl:][:cntrl:]]+$', null, 1, 0, 'm');
```

Explanation: first it eliminates all rows which starts with 'PARTITION' except starting with 'PARTITION BY', then it eliminates the empty rows resulted of the first "masking".